# php multidimensional array problem

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

i am trying to setup a multidimensional array but my problem is that i can not get the right order from incoming data.

Explain

```
$x[1][11]=11;
$x[1]=1;

var_dump($x);
```

In the above code i get only x[1].

To right would be

```
$x[1]=1;
$x[1][11]=11;

var_dump($x);
```

But in my case i can dot ensure that x[1] will come first, and x[1][11] will come after.

Is there any way that i can use the first example and get right the array.
Keep in mind that the array depth is large.

I am trying to get an array as tree

```
$x[node]=node data
$x[node][childs]=childs data
etc..
```

and from incoming data is not sure that node will come first and child second and i am looking for a solution to create the array right

Thanks

Comment: You have completely changed the story by saying that you are trying to build a tree. Now it would be critically useful to know what your incoming data looks like.

Answer (score 2):

If you set `$x[1]` to be `1`, then it's a number.
If you set `$x[1][11]` to anything, than `$x[1]` is an **array**.
It can't be a number and an array at the same time.

```
$x = array(
    1 => 1
);

$x = array(
    1 => array(
        11 => 11
    )
);
```

You'll have to rethink what structure you actually want.

---

If you really need each node to both have a value *and* children, you'll have to go with something like this:

```
array(
    1 => array(
        'value' => 1,
        'children' => array(
            11 => array(
                'value' => 11,
                'children' => array( ... )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Case One:

```
// make $x[1] equal to array(11 => 11)
$x[1][11]=11;

// make $x[1] equal to 1
$x[1]=1;

// result, $x[1] is equal to 1
```

Case Two:

```
// make $x[1] equal to 1
$x[1]=1;

// make $x[1] equal to array(11 => 11)
$x[1][11]=11;

// result, $x[1] is equal to array(11 => 11)
```

I do not know what you really want `$x[1]` to be. I am going to assume you might want this:

```
// make $x[1] equal to array(1)
$x[1][] = 1;

// append 11, making $x[1] equal to array(1, 11)
$x[1][] = 11;

// result, $x[1] is equal to array(1, 11)
```

Or you might just want this:

```
// make $x equal to array(1)
$x[] = 1;

// append 11, making $x equal to array(1, 11)
$x[] = 11;

// result, $x is equal to array(1, 11)
```

Comment: I agree but its and array tree and i can not get the right tree order so i have to build the array based on the incoming data

Answer (score 0):

You can't set `$x[1]` *and* `$x[1][11]` at the same time. Remember that in setting `$x[1][11]`  you're creating an array with an array like `array(11 => 11)` and assigning that array to `$x[1]`. What you're trying to do is have both `1` and the array in `$x[1]`, which isn't possible.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you're redefining it.

```
$x[1][11]=11; // $x[1] is Array(11 => 11)
$x[1]=1; // $x[1] is int(1)

var_dump($x); // Will output Array(1 => 1)
```

and with your second example...

```
$x[1]=1; // $x[1] is int(1)
$x[1][11]=11; // $x[1] is Array(11 => 11)

var_dump($x); // Will output int(1)
```

I don't know exactly, but I think what you want to be doing is this:

```
$x[1][1]=1; // $x[1] is Array(1 => 1)
$x[1][11]=11; // $x[1] is Array(1 => 1, 11 => 11)

var_dump($x); // Will output Array(1 => 1, 11 => 11)
```

Answer (score 0):

The other posters are exactly right - you're overwriting the value of `$x[1]` with an array. If you want a tree structure that allows internal nodes to be labelled, you're looking at something like [a trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie):

```
class Node {
  public $value = null, $children = array();
  public function set($keys, $value) {
    if (empty($keys)) {
      $this->value = $value;
      return;
    }
    $key = array_shift($keys);
    if (!isset($this->children[$key])) {
      $this->children[$key] = new Node();
    }
    $child = $this->children[$key];
    $child->set($keys, $value);
  }
}

$trie = new Node();
$trie->set(array(1), 1);
$trie->set(array(1, 11), 11);
print_r($trie);
```